# Retrying tasks with Django-Celery - Django/Celery

Tags: python, django, scheduled-tasks, celery, django-celery

I'm having problems retrying tasks, here is what a test task looks like

```
from celery.decorators import task

@task()
def add(x, y):
    if not x or not y:
        raise Exception("test error")
    return x+y
```

I cannot find any documentation what-so-ever on how to retry decorated tasks, all I found was this:

```
self.retry(x,y, exc=exception, countdown=30)
```

which doesn't seem to work with my case as there is not `self` variable being passed from the method.

### Edit:

I'm trying the following now to no avail:

```
from celery.decorators import task

@task()
def add(x, y):
    if not x or not y:
        try:
            raise Exception("test error")
        except Exception, e:
            add.retry([x, y], exc=e, countdown=30)
    return x+y
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError("kwargs argument to retries can't be empty. Task must accept **kwargs, see [http://bit.ly/cAx3Bg](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#retrying)",)

Comment: There is no self because your task is not *bound*.  This is a new concept in Celery 3.1: `@task(bind=True) def add(self, x, y):`.  If you use an earlier version you must reference the name of the task: `add.retry(...)`.

Comment: Also, you get the last error because you didn't specify keyword arguments for the task: `add.retry([x, y], {}, exc=e, countdown=30) ought to work, but you don't have to specify `x` and `y` here (unless the function changed their values)`, because `retry` will automatically use the arguments used to invoke the task: `add.retry(exc=e, countdown=30)`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The task needs to accept keyword arguments, they are used to pass information amongst other about the retry count. I think the code should look like this:

```
from celery.decorators import task

@task()
def add(x, y, **kwargs):
    if not x or not y:
        try:
            raise Exception("test error")
        except Exception, e:
            add.retry(args=[x, y], exc=e, countdown=30, kwargs=kwargs)
    return x+y
```

`**kwargs` need to be added to the signature of the `add` function, and passed as `kwargs=kwargs` when calling retry.

Note: this style [was deprecated with the release of celery 2.2](http://readthedocs.org/docs/celery/en/master/changelog.html#v220-important).

Comment: Yup, in the latest version it seems that it's good enough to just do add.retry(exc=e, countdown=30) ... where add is replaced with whatever the name of the decorated task/method is.

Answer (score 28):

You can set your retry parameters in the decorator:

```
@task(default_retry_delay=5 * 60, max_retries=12)
def foo(bar):
  try:
      ...
  except Exception, exc:
      raise foo.retry(exc=exc)
```